# Nest JS Factorize Error handling in resolver

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs

I have a resolver file for my User with some mutations on it to update, delete, markInactive and banUser

```
  async updateUser(
    @Args() { id, input },
  ) {
    const user = await this.userService.getById(id);
    if (!user) {
      return new NotFoundError('User not found');
    }

    const isAdminUser = this.userService.isUserAdmin(id);
    if (!isAdminUser) {
      return new PermissionError(`You can't update this user cause it's an admin `);
    }

    const user = await this.userService.update(id, input);

    return {
      id: user.id,
      user
    };
  }


 async deleteUser(
    @Args() { id, input },
  ) {
    const user = await this.userService.getById(id);
    if (!user) {
      return new NotFoundError('User not found');
    }

    const isAdminUser = this.userService.isUserAdmin(id);
    if (!isAdminUser) {
      return new PermissionError(`You can't update this user cause it's an admin`);
    }

    const user = await this.userService.delete(id, input);

    return {
      id: user.id,
      user
    };
  }

 async deleteUser(
    @Args() { id, input },
  ) {
    const user = await this.userService.getById(id);
    if (!user) {
      return new NotFoundError('User not found');
    }

    const isAdminUser = this.userService.isUserAdmin(id);
    if (!isAdminUser) {
      return new PermissionError(`You can't update this user cause it's an admin`);
    }

    const user = await this.userService.delete(id, input);

    return {
      id: user.id,
      user
    };
  }

 async markInactive(
    @Args() { id },
  ) {
    const user = await this.userService.getById(id);
    if (!user) {
      return new NotFoundError('User not found');
    }

    const isAdminUser = this.userService.isUserAdmin(id);
    if (!isAdminUser) {
      return new PermissionError(`You can't update this user cause it's an admin`);
    }

    const user = await this.userService.markInactive(id);

    return {
      id: user.id,
      user
    };
  }


 async banUser(
    @Args() { id },
  ) {
    const user = await this.userService.getById(id);
    if (!user) {
      return new NotFoundError('User not found');
    }

    const isAdminUser = this.userService.isUserAdmin(id);
    if (!isAdminUser) {
      return new PermissionError(`You can't update this user cause it's an admin`);
    }

    const user = await this.userService.banUser(id);

    return {
      id: user.id,
      user
    };
  }
```

I always repeat the error handler (check user exist and check the user is admin) in all my resolver and now I need to add two update mutation, but I want to find a way to factorize this error checking in a common function

Do you have a solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great usecase here for refactoring. I would suggest you two approaches. Note that some parts are only guesses as I don't know your code base.

### Using a repetitve approach

Since these methods are doing the same thing, you can move the logic somewhere else :

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  async getById(userId: string): Promise<User> {
    // just an example 
    const user = { id: '1', isAdmin: false };

    return Promise.resolve(user);
  }

  async ensuresUserExists(userId: string): Promise<void> {
    const user = await this.getById(userId);

    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundError('User not found');
    }
  }

  async ensuresUserIsNotAdmin(userId: string): Promise<void> {
    const user = await this.getById(userId);

    if (!user) {
      throw new PermissionError("You can't update this user cause it's an admin");
    }
  }
}
```

You can simply use this in your controller methods:

```
  async updateUser(
    @Args() { id, input },
  ) {
    await this.userService.ensuresUserExists(id);
    await this.userService.ensuresUserIsNotAdmin(id);

    const user = await this.userService.update(id, input);

    return {
      id: user.id,
      user
    };
  }
```

I think most ORMs will throw an error if user does not exist anyway, I assume you can go deeper and make sures the user exists and is not admin in the same method but again I don't know what is your architecture.

### Using guards

NestJs allows you to create custom [guards](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) where you can perform any operations prior to a method execution. It's IMO a cleaner approach.

guard.ts

```
export const ADMIN_OP = 'admin';

@Injectable()
export class UserEditGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector, private userService: UserService) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    const operationType = this.reflector.get<string>(
      'operationType',
      context.getHandler(),
    );

    if (operationType !== ADMIN_OP) return true;

    const { userId } = request.body; // assuming you are sending params in POST request body

    if (!userId) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(); 
    }

    await this.userService.ensuresUserExists(userId);
    await this.userService.ensuresUserIsNotAdmin(userId);

    return true;
  }
}
```

Now you just need to "plug" the guard to your method.

```
export const UserPermissionCheck = () => SetMetadata('operationType', ADMIN_OP); // This will add the type to metadata
```

And then add it to your Controller (this will work with a service too)

```
@Controller()
@UseGuards(UserEditGuard)
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

  @Post()
  @UserPermissionCheck()
  async updateUser(@Body() { id, input }) {
    const user = await this.userService.update(id, input);

    return {
      id: user.id,
      user,
    };
  }

  @Post()
  @UserPermissionCheck()
  async deleteUser(@Body() { id, input }) {
    const user = await this.userService.delete(id, input);

    return {
      id: user.id,
      user,
    };
  }
}
```